# where should data integrity be maintained?

Tags: django, postgresql, rdbms, ordbms

The simplified scenario first:

- Merchants have products
- Merchants have categories
- Products have subcategories
- A merchant's products' categories must have the merchant's category as the parent category

This is modelled using the RDBMS approach. I'm using Postgres for my database and Django as the web framework. We have features such as enabling/disabling a product/category/merchant. The effects of these must cascade and the data should remain consistent. Where should this be handled ? I can have triggers in my DB to enforce this, or use methods/signals like pre save/post save, pre init/post init in my Django models to do the same. Which is more appropriate. I'm more comfortable with python than SQL, and believe that doing it via Django models makes it more modifiable, since In my company the requirements are prone to frequent and sudden changes.

Comment: There are advantages and disadvantages for both approaches, and there are many details that are missing in order to make a proper decision.

Comment: what information would you like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's indeed about *data* integrity, do it within Postgres, it will be much much easier to *stay* consistent when your data model expands.

(I've grown an application from about 10 to about 70 tables, the parts of the data model which where ensured by DB schema have been clean ever since. The parts which *tried* to maintain a consistency allegedly on a "higher" level screwed up now and then)

If it's about the *behaviour* of the application, do it in django.

Comment: This is so opinion based.

Comment: I agree in part. It is also about best practices in designing your data model

Comment: Why did you do it for parts of the data model only. If you had decided to let the dbms handle it, why did you not stick with it ?

Comment: All of these played a role: 1) design by committee 2) the model was in hindsight not well enough thought through 3) soft-coding antipattern

Comment: @ knitti & @EagerNoob: "If it's about the behaviour of the application" is maybe misleading. Behaviour is parameterized/affected by the database so better would be, if it's*only* about the behaviour of the application". But best is, the/a database can and should contain as much application session control flow and session state as practical. (Ie *proper* soft-coding.)